# Não consigo fazer o evento change de um Dropdown funcionar - JS e Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um Combobox personalizado e dentro dele um button com menus e submenus. Quando eu clicar em um elemento da tag  (Por exemplo, um e-mail) ele deve usar o evento change e capturar o conteúdo de data-id e jogá-lo em uma variável. Não sei o que estou fazendo errado, mas não consigo fazer que seja disparado o evento change... Estou tentando chamar o id="btn-add-contato" do dropdown, mas não funciona... Alguém me ajuda?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="dropdown" style="z-index:10000; position:absolute" id="btn-add-contato">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Novo Contato
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleDefaultDropdownSubMenu" role="menu">
        <div class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" tabindex="-1">Telefones</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @foreach (var item in Model.FormasContato)
                {
                    switch (item.Value)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon fa-tty" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon wb-mobile" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon md-headset-mic" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" tabindex="-1">WEB</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @foreach (var item in Model.FormasContato)
                {
                    switch (item.Value)
                    {
                        case "5":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon wb-envelope" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon wb-chat-group" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                        case "8":
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon fa-users" aria-hidden="true" data-id="@item.Value"></i>@item.Text</a>
                            break;
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('change', '#btn-add-contato', function (e) {
    alert('Disparou o evento!');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer a atribuição do evento `onChange()` assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn-add-contato').on('change', function (e) {
      alert('Disparou o evento!');
  });
})
```

Comment: Olá @Victor Laio! Acho que tem um problema com esse dropdown, pois ele possui um button dentro dele. Ele não foi elaborado para guardar uma opção quando clicado (ex: e-mail). Acho que o evento click funcionaria... Eu alterei sua sugestão, em vez de "change", para "click" e funcionou, porém preciso que ele dispare o click sobre os submenus e não sobre os menus (Telefones e WEB)... Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Entao inspeciona o elemento através do navegador e vc vai poder ver se ele realmente fez a atribuição do evento ou até mesmo se existe um button dento dele. Assim você vai pegar realmente o id que necessita para fazer o change()

Comment: É... Eu inspecionei e realmente tem um button dentro. Não sei se é uma forma correta, mas funcionou! Fui referenciando todas as classes filhas até chegar em .dropdown-item... Assim, o clique será disparado apenas nos elementos itens de cada menu do submenu:  $('#btn-add-contato .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item').on('click', function (e) {

Comment: Obrigado @Victor Laio!